# Symfony2 Embed Form in SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

i have two entities Ticket and comment 
i want to embed commentType inside TicketType
using sonata admin generator bundle

Comment: Is there a OneToOne/OneToMany association between the two?